# Defining a map into $S^1$ as an "angle" in a non simply connected domain

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that ambient space is $\mathbb R^2$, and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ is a smooth domain, non simply connected domain. To fix ideas,we can assume  $$\Omega = \{(x_1,x_2) : 1< x_1^2+x_2^2 <4\}.$$

Given $p\geq2$, if $V$ is simply connected, given a function $\phi\in W^{1,p}(V;S^1)$ there exists $\theta \in W^{1,p}(V,\mathbb R)$ such that
$$
\phi = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)).
$$

This is well known, see comments below (which date from an earlier formulation of this post).

It isn't the case here ($\phi = x/|x|$ for example) . But what can be said? That there is a  smooth lift taking values in, say $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ ? Does such a result exist ?

What I have found are results saying that if the domain is not simply connected, it isn't as usual. But they do not dwell on what happens then.

To clarify, I am aware that if we make a cut somewhere, then we can define an angle. But this unfolding of the domain does not appeal to me, as I am interested in a variational problems and it would require me to specify some sort of boundary condition on the cut, which I don't want to do.

Given a map $\phi$ taking values in $S^1$, since $\phi^T\phi =1$, what you can always say is that
$$
D\phi^T\phi = 0 \text{ and } \phi^T D\phi =0, 
$$
and therefore the gradient is at most of rank one. Writing $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 \\ -1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$, since $\phi,J\phi$ are orthogonal, this means that writing $ z =D\phi^T J\phi$, one has
$$
D\phi = J\phi z^T.
$$
My question is: is $z$ the gradient of something?

Comment: Perhaps further up in the text they have specified that $\Omega$ is simply connected? Otherwise you run into the issue you mention.

Comment: @KevinCasto thank you yes, probably. What happens in that case though?

Comment: Then the claim is true -- any continuous map from a simply connected space to $S^1$ is null-homotopic and therefore lifts to a map to $\mathbb R$. This is just basic algebraic topology, at least in the continuous category. I'm sure it's straightforward to extend this result to $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: @KevinCasto I meant in the case when the domain isn't simply connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be connected. There is a lifting criterion: A map $f:\Omega\rightarrow S^1$ lifts to the universal cover $\mathbb R\rightarrow S^1$ iff $f_*(\pi_1(\Omega))=0$, where $f_*$ is the induced map $f_*:\pi_1(\Omega)\rightarrow \pi_1(S^1)$. Your space $W^{1,p}(\Omega,S^1)$ has different connected components: There is one connected component (namely those for which the criterion before is satisfied)  for which the lifts are possible.

In general you cannot lift a map to the universal cover. However subgroups of the fundamental group of index $k$ correspond to $k$ fold covers. For the circle the cover is again a circle, only wrapped around the base circle $k$ times.

Over the other components of $W^{1,p}(\Omega,S^1)$, where $f_*(\pi_1(\Omega))$ is the index $k$ subgroup, you can lift to the $k$ fold cover of $S^1$ (which is still $S^1$).

Comment: Thank you that is probably very helpful --that's not a language I am familiar with but I'll try to understand what it means. To take the example of $x/|x|$ in the domain described, which subgroups would it belong to? Is there such as thing as a lift from $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ to $S^1$?

Comment: in the case described the subgroup is $\mathbb Z$ itself.

Comment: You can have a look at Hatcher's algebraic topology book. This is discussed in the section on the fundamental group and covering spaces.

Comment: Hatcher's Algebraic Geometry is very useful ([Pierre Albin's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpRLWqLFLVTCL15U6N3o35g4uhMSBVA2b) on this book are very helpful) to understand your answer. Yet I think your answer doesn't answer my question, it describes what the space looks like, and why I cannot map to $\mathbb{R}$. I think the answer to my question is simply "yes" : there is a lift taking values in $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$.